# Combining jssor slider types

Tags: jssor

I would like to combine a list slider with the banner slider and create a slider that shows the thumbnail for the slider on the left side and has the title bar across the bottom.

how can this be done.

Comment: Could you add some more details to your question like, for example, what have you tried todo?

Answer (score 0):

You can add thumbnail navigator to any slider.

With the 'demos-jquery\banner-slider.source.html' demo, please go through the following steps,

1. Adjust layout of 'sliderb_container' and the 'slides' container to reserve 200px (width) space for thumbnail navigator.

   replace `width: 600px;' with 'width: 800px;' to get code as below,

   ```
   <div id="sliderb_container" style="position: relative; width: 800px;
       height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
   ```

   replace `left: 0px;' with 'left: 200px;' to get code as below,

   ```
   <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
   ```
2. Copy thumbnail navigator from 'demos-jquery\list-slider.source.html', and paste to your banner slider. (please make sure to replace `left:605px;` with `left:0px;`)

   ```
   <div id="sliderb_container' ...>
       ...
       <div u="slides" ...>
           ...
       </div>
       ...
       <!-- ThumbnailNavigator Skin Begin -->
       <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort11" style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 300px; left:0px; top:0px;">
           <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
           <style>
               /* thumbnail navigator css here */
           </style>
           <div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
               <div u="prototype" class="p" style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 69px; top: 0; left: 0;">
                   <div u="thumbnailtemplate" style=" width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
       </div>
       <!-- ThumbnailNavigator Skin End -->
   </div>
   ```
3. Add thumbnail navigator options to your banner slider.

   ```
   var options = {
       ...,
       $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
           $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
           $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

           $Loop: 2,                                       //[Optional] Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1
           $AutoCenter: 3,                                 //[Optional] Auto center thumbnail items in the thumbnail navigator container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 3
           $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
           $SpacingX: 4,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
           $SpacingY: 4,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
           $Cols: 4,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
           $Align: 0,                            //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
           $Orientation: 2,                                //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
           $DisableDrag: false                             //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
       },
       ...
   };
   ```